# URLClassLoader throws No Class Definition found exception

Tags: java, urlclassloader

I have 3 Java projects A, B and C. 
B is like an add-on to A. A and B both depend on project C for some classes.

Now in project A when I use a URLClassLoader as follows:

```
URLClassLoader ucl = new URLClassLoader(urls); //urls are paths to some classes in B
```

Now when using these ucl, when I call some methods in B, it gives me **No Class Definition found exception**. This is for a class which is C.

Now when I use the ClassLoader as follows:

```
ClassLoader classLoader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
URLClassLoader ucl = new URLClassLoader(urls, classLoader);
```

This works fine when I call the methods in B. 
My Question:

1) When I do it the first way, which ClassLoader is being used? I read the JavaDocs, but couldn't find anything that I could explain myself to.
2) Is there a way to get a ClassLoader which will be specific to project B, that I can use somehow, so that I won't hit any dependency issues?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default class loader is the system class loader (loads the classes on the classpath).

If you loaded classes in B with a specific class loader, use that instance. Otherwise `someTypeInB.getClass().getClassLoader()` will do as a hack.

(Note: Using `URLClassLoader.newInstance` is generally preferable to `new URLClassLoader`, as it adds in security measures necessary (though not really sufficient) for use with untrusted code. Also using the thread context class loader is generally a bad idea - you introduce a dependency upon the local piece of code to however threads are setup and used [which probably doesn't have any coherent policy applied to it anyway].)

Comment: Thanks for the pointers. I will look into these things. One small question though. B is like an add-on to A, so A does not know anything about B. So I cannot use 'someTypeInB.getClass().getClassLoader()' inside A...

Comment: Note that you can find your current class loader with `this.getClass().getClassLoader()`.  This is the context that you would use if you simply loaded a class from your current class.

Comment: @Daniel One-arg `Class.forName` will usually suffice (it's a method with very odd behaviour). @rgamber If I am following what you are doing correctly, you should create a class loader for B and then just keep hold of the reference along with any other pointers you have into B.

Comment: @Daniel For loading a class from the same (or a parent) class loader of the calling class.

Comment: Yes, but you also may want that class loader so you can use it as a parent of the CL you're creating.

Comment: @Tom: Well this seems more complicated than I initially thought. B is like a plugin onto A so A only knows one generic class in B that it loads as above. So I dont have pointers to it..(might have to have it eventually though). @ Daniel: this.getClass().getClassLoader() won't work when called from A as it wont be able to load any dependebcies of B..

Answer (score 1):

When you use your first URLClassLoader, the one initialized only with a path for B, then if something in B needs to resolve something in C in order to load, it will come up short.  By using the second form you're saying "If you don't find what you need here, look in the 'parent' class loader."  This allows C to be resolved and everyone's happy.

(Understand that the only class that can load without referencing other classes is Object -- and even that's a stretch.  It's not just that you need to reference the class's superclass -- objects in the base JDK, at least, can be referenced through the system class loader even when there is no parent CL -- but if you call any method of another class or manipulate pointers to another class or any such thing you need to resolve that referenced class.)